# post install script fails to find Android SDK

Tags: android, bash, macos, sdk

Can't figure out why I'm getting this error upon running a post install script

`You must set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the path of your installation of the Android SDK.`

Based on what I have observed in other questions it seems it might be that my environment variables are not pointing to the right part of the SDK. Here is what I have in my .zprofile

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/djr/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

This is on an Apple silicon MacBook Pro running 12.1.
It is a .js script being executed by node

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls /Users/djr/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: build-tools emulator licenses patcher  platform-tools platforms tools

Answer (score 0):

You should add those lines to the startup file that belongs to your login shell (e.g. `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`).

Then before invoking `node` verify the variables are set with the expected values.

```
$ ls "$ANDROID_HOME"
```

can give you a clue if the value is correct.

It's not possible to change the environment of a parent process (*perhpas you are invoking `node` expecting it to change the environment of the parent shell*).

Comment: I appreciate the help but this didn’t work for some reason

Comment: Which part? Did you add it to your startup file? Did you verify with `ls`?

Comment: Added it where you told me. Tried to verify and got nothing.

Comment: If by *verify* you mean running `ls` as mentioned, *nothing* seems to be not possible as `ls` either shows files or an error message.

Comment: sorry here is what I found  

```build-tools emulator licenses patcher  platform-tools platforms tools```